# Google Analytics JS by Example

Tags: javascript, google-analytics

I am trying to get my JS pages reporting basic metrics back to my GA account. However the Google docs don't really *cleanly*/*consistently* clarify how to accomplish this. On one hand you have the `analytics.js` snippet:

```
<!-- Google Analytics -->
<script>
(function(i,s,o,g,r,a,m){i['GoogleAnalyticsObject']=r;i[r]=i[r]||function(){
(i[r].q=i[r].q||[]).push(arguments)},i[r].l=1*new Date();a=s.createElement(o),
m=s.getElementsByTagName(o)[0];a.async=1;a.src=g;m.parentNode.insertBefore(a,m)
})(window,document,'script','//www.google-analytics.com/analytics.js','ga');

ga('create', 'UA-XXXX-Y', 'auto');
ga('send', 'pageview');

</script>
<!-- End Google Analytics -->
```

But this doesn't show how you actually tie the `ga` function to your GA account/client ID.

Then you have [this behemoth of JS](https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/reporting/core/v3/quickstart/web-js), but that looks totally different than the first snippet above. So I ask, can someone explain and provide an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/) of the required JS to actually send basic metrics back from a page?

Comment: The documentation for doing that is on the developers site you linked to. It's impossible to help you if we don't know what (specifically) you're actually trying to accomplish. You should update your question to ask how to do something specific or point to places where the documentation isn't clear.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> But this doesn't show how you actually tie the ga function to your GA account/client ID.

You just put the [tracking ID](https://ga-dev-tools.appspot.com/account-explorer/) (which will be of a format like `UA-XXXXX-Y`) in the `UA-XXXXX-Y` spot. Nothing else requires changing.

Incidentally, GA will give you the exact code, including the tracking ID, in the `Admin > Tracking Info` section, as well as when you first create the account/property.

---

[image]

---

[image]

> Then you have this behemoth of JS, but that looks totally different than the first snippet above.

That's for getting data *out* of GA, like for a custom dashboard. If you just want to look at pretty stats in the Google Analytics interface, ignore that bit of documentation.